# Separation of Variables question deriving without defined values

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am encountering questions like this below.

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=(a-b\cos t ) \left(P+ \frac{P^2}{M}\right)$$

Then there is information stating $M$ is a positive integer and $a$ and $b$ are positive. That when $t=0$, $P=P_0$.

It wants me to solve the differential equation and show the process.

How am I supposed to derive this? I suspect it is a separation of variables question but I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone point me in the direction of an exercise or explanation video.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition is the key

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by the factor on the right,
$$\left(P + \frac{P^2}{M}\right)^{-1} \frac{dP}{dt} = a - b\cos t.$$ Integrating both sides with respect to $t$,

$$\int_0^t \left(P + \frac{P^2}{M}\right)^{-1} \frac{dP}{ds}ds  = \int_0^t (a - b\cos s) ds.$$
U(/P)-substitution... partial fraction decomp...

Comment: It doesn't mean that $t=0$ in general, just that when $t=0$, $P=P_0$. Since $P=P(t)$ is a function of $t$, this means that $P(0) = P_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dP}{P+\frac{P^2}{M}}=\int[a-b\cos(t)]dt
\end{align}
The left integral is
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dP}{P+\frac{P^2}{M}}=\int\Big(\frac{1}{P}-\frac{1}{M+P}\Big)dP=\ln P-\ln(M+P)=\ln\Big(\frac{P}{M+P}\Big)
\end{align}
The right integral is
\begin{align}
\int[a-b\cos(t)]dt=at-b\sin(t)+c
\end{align}
We now get
\begin{align}
P(t)=\frac{Me^{at-b\sin(t)+c}}{1-e^{at-b\sin(t)+c}}
\end{align}
With $P(t=0)=P_0$ you get the equation $P_0=\frac{M}{e^{-c}-1}$ which you have to solve it for $c$. The solution is $c=-\ln(\tfrac{M}{P_0}+1)$